# Remove words and print most common in Python

Tags: python, nltk, counter

I'm working with `Python` `Counter` and `nltk`. I'm trying to search words on an external document erase some words with `stopwrods`, and then show the most common ones. But an error appear that I don't know how to solve it:

```
AttributeError: 'Counter' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Any idea how to go on?

```
from collections import Counter
import io
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
#word_tokenize accepts a string as an input, not a file.
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('spanish'))
file1 = open("labs.txt")
line = file1.read()# Use this to read file content as a stream:
words = line.split()
for r in words:
    if not r in stop_words:
        with open("labs.txt") as input_file:
            vonCount = Counter(word for line in input_file for word in line.split())
            vonCount.write(" "+r)
            print(vonCount.most_common(70))
```

Comment: Get rid of the line `vonCount.write(" "+r)`

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
from collections import Counter
import io
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
#word_tokenize accepts a string as an input, not a file.
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('spanish'))
file1 = open("labs.txt")
line = file1.read()# Use this to read file content as a stream:
words = line.split()
for r in words:
    if not r in stop_words:
        appendFile = open('cambio.txt','a')
        appendFile.write(" "+r)
        appendFile.close()
        
with open("cambio.txt") as input_file:
    vonCount = Counter(word for line in input_file for word in line.split())
    print(vonCount.most_common(7))
```